# Read HttpWebResponse using Tls11 C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to make a POST request to a website using C#. 
I tried this code first :

```
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.foo.com");


                WebReq.Method = "POST";
                WebReq.Accept = "*/*";
                WebReq.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
                WebReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
                WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

                Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
                PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                PostData.Close();
                HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
                Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
                String reply = _Answer.ReadToEnd();
                //do some tasks on reply
```

Turns out that this always returned this error : "underlying connection was closed..."

I found out that it's because the site only accepts TLS. So I added this at the beggining of the code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

The site accepted the request, but now I can't read the response I'm getting, it's encrypted to something like this :

```
��;ks�J���+&�$�� zYK)�NN�{������TJ5� � ��`���o�H �؎]��(K0��~�>~|����}NbL?��ϾG^='�/�����~<�k$��|��P�
```

I need to perform some tasks on the response, so I need to decrypt it within the code... I'm open to ideas ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you sure it's UTF8? You've probably just got the wrong encoding. Have you tried Unicode or ASCII?

Comment: I tried with ASCII and Unicode, still getting the same encrypted response...

Comment: And you're sure it's TLS 1.1, 1.2 is more common now. Does the API not have any documentation?

Comment: I tried both TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2, didn't work. I made the same request using hurl.it and the response wasn't encrypted. I did the same using JAVA, and got a normal response aswell. Changing language is not an option for me, so I gotta figure out why it can't work on c#